# Google map Joomla error

Tags: javascript, joomla

Im trying to use google map on this site in the footer where the BRANCHES CONTACT INFO are it should be on the right next to the address but there is a conflict or error not sure what the problem is
here is the site http://consultgp.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

When i look at your website, i've notice you've got JS error

> ReferenceError: google is not defined

basicly you don't have included google map api file, at head tag, you should have something like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All because you use 'Modules Anywhere' inside Custom Module. To fix it, you need to edit your Custom Module, go to Option Tab, and change 'Prepare Content' to Yes.
With this option, all plugins, and libraries will load.
More about this option you can find at joomla docs.